# How do I un-stick the release button on my Yale door knob?

Tags: doors, lock

I'm rekeying my door locks (Yale door knob/locks). To remove the knob, you press in the release button & slide the knob off. The release button is stuck and I can't depress it enough to slide the knob off. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You have to put in the key and turn it while pressing the release button (or anyone could remove the knob and break in).